# How to break up a django form with back and next button

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I've this contact us model and would like to separate it into 2 sections:

1. name, email, contact number
2. subject, message

How do I separate these 2 sections into different pages with a BACK and NEXT buttons?

models.py

```
class ContactUs(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=850)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

html

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                <form method="POST" action='{% url "contact" %}' role="form" id="contact-form" class="contact-form"> {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name*" value="{{ name }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail*" value="{{ email }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_number" id="contact_number" placeholder="Contact Number" value="{{ contact_number }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" value="{{ subject }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control textarea" rows="3" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message*">{{ message }}</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary2 btn-xl page-scroll pull-right">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

forms.py

```
class ContactUsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactUs
        fields = ["name",
                "email",
                "contact_number",
                "subject",
                "message",]
```

Comment: What if you set all of the values to blank=True, besides name making that the primary key, then you can have two forms one for the first part then on the press of next it saves the form and redirect to the second form allowing you to input the rest of the data, using name as the common grounds to save both of the forms in the same object. Do you get what I'm saying, if you want me to put it in an answer just let me know? There may be an easier way to do it though, this is just how I would do it personally.

Answer (score 0):

Up to Django 1.7, you would use the form tools that were shipped with Django.
They were moved out of Django with release 1.8 though. You can find them in a separate module now: https://github.com/django/django-formtools

Among other stuff, it features a so-called [form wizard](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wizard.html) which does exactly what you're looking for.

The documentation is pretty thorough, there is not much I could add without just copy-pasting the code example from there. The [creating templates for the forms](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wizard.html#creating-templates-for-the-forms) section has an example with a back and a previous button in it.